# Why couldn't start ExpressJS ? Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to start a ExpressJS server on my Windows machine, i'm using the latest ExpressJS (4.16.4) and Node Version 10.2.1. However, I keep getting the same error.

```
Listen to http://localhost: 61016
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:61016
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Repo\dasho\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.start (C:\Repo\dasho\server\index.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Repo\dasho\server\index.js:78:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Repo\dasho\server.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have something listening on the port already.

You can:

```
netstat -anon | findstr 61016
```

And then grab the process ID from that and run:

```
kill processid
```

This should kill whatever is running on it.

Comment: No, the Port 61016 is not in used.

Comment: Do you need higher level permissions? Like running the command prompt as admin?

Comment: it has nothing to do with permissions, i get the same error even if i start the console with admin right

Comment: You're not seeing anything listening on 61016?

Comment: no, there is no other application that listening on the same port.

Comment: Did you try any other port?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the node_modules folder incl. package-lock file and now it works.